# MySQL UDF/Stored function not recognizing table name passed as an argument

Tags: mysql, function, parameter-passing

The following is the stored function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `calcMedian`(
    `tbl` VARCHAR(64),
    `clm` VARCHAR(64)
) RETURNS decimal(14,4)
BEGIN

    SELECT AVG(middle_values) AS 'median'
    INTO medRslt
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.clm AS 'middle_values'
        FROM
        (
            SELECT @row:=@row+1 as `row`, table_column_name
            FROM tbl, (SELECT @row:=0) AS r
            ORDER BY clm
        ) AS t1,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) as 'count'
            FROM tbl        
        ) AS t2

        WHERE t1.row >= t2.count/2 and t1.row <= ((t2.count/2) +1)) AS t3;  
    RETURN medRslt; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I then proceed to execute the following query:

```
USE ap2;

SELECT vendor_id, calcMedian('invoices', 'invoice_total')
FROM invoices i
WHERE vendor_id = 97
GROUP BY vendor_id;
```

I get the error message:

```
SQL Error (1146): Table 'ap2.tbl' doesn't exist *
```

I understand that the following may be better off as stored procedure/prepared statement rather than function. I just want to take things one step at a time now.

Also I made a different function to simply output the value stored in the variable 'tbl', and it displayed the correct table name (invoices in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers in a SQL statement cannot be provided as values. Identifiers (table names, column names, function names, etc.) must be specified in the SQL text.

To get the value of the `tbl` variable (procedure argument) used as a table name within a SQL statement in the procedure, you can use **dynamic SQL**.

Set a variable to the SQL text, incorporate the string value, and then execute the string as a SQL statement. As an example:

```
  SET @sql = CONCAT( 'SELECT AVG(middle_values) AS `median`'
                   , ' INTO medRslt'
                   , ' ... '
                   , tbl
                   , ' ... '
             );
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

---

Be aware that incorporating string values into the SQL text makes the procedure subject to SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

If I had to do this, I would reduce the potential for SQL Injection by verifying that `tbl` does not contain a backtick character, and enclose/escape the identifier in backticks, e.g.

```
   CONCAT( ' ...' , '`' , tbl , '`' , ' ... ' );
                    ^^^         ^^^
```